# stderr in dplyr (R): What am I doing wrong?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to calculate year-wise standard error for the variable AcrePrice. I'm running the function stderr (also tried with sd(acrePrice)/count(n)). Both of these return an error.

Here's the relevant code:

```
library(alr4)
library(tidyverse)

MinnLand %>% group_by(year) %>% summarize(sd(acrePrice)/count(n))
MinnLand %>% group_by(year) %>% summarize(stderr(acrePrice))
```

Why is there a problem? The mean and SDs are easily calculated.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with the first function is `count`, which requires a data.frame, instead it would be `n()`

```
library(dplyr)
MinnLand %>%
     group_by(year) %>%
     summarize(SE = sd(acrePrice)/n(), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
#    year    SE
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  2002 2.25 
# 2  2003 0.840
# 3  2004 0.742
# 4  2005 0.862
# 5  2006 0.849
# 6  2007 0.765
# 7  2008 0.708
# 8  2009 1.23 
# 9  2010 0.986
#10  2011 1.95
```

---

According to `?stderr`

> stdin(), stdout() and stderr() are standard connections corresponding to input, output and error on the console respectively (and not necessarily to file streams).

We can use `std.error` from `plotrix`

```
library(plotrix)
MinnLand %>%
       group_by(year) %>%
       summarize(SE = std.error(acrePrice))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
#    year    SE
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  2002  53.4
# 2  2003  38.6
# 3  2004  37.0
# 4  2005  41.5
# 5  2006  39.7
# 6  2007  36.3
# 7  2008  34.9
# 8  2009  47.1
# 9  2010  42.1
#10  2011  63.6
```

Comment: @AmoghJoshi  the `stderr` is a base R function for a different purpose

Comment: @AmoghJoshi `stdin(), stdout() and stderr() are standard connections corresponding to input, output and error on the console respectively (and not necessarily to file streams).`

Comment: If you want to use standard error, it should be a from a package

Comment: Ohh. Okay. Thanks!

Comment: @AmoghJoshi i used `std.error`, but the values are different because the algorithm is different in calculation than the one you used

Comment: Yup. I got that. One more question, you mentioned that there is a problem with count() function. class(MinnLand) outputs as a data.frame. 

What's the difference between count() and n()?

Comment: @AmoghJoshi `count` gives a column with a frequency count. i.e. `count(iris, Species)` which can also be done with `n()` using `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(n = n())`